# MacBook goes into clamshell sleep immediately

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have installed a few apps and MacBook started to went back to sleep as soon as it woke up. If I switch to another user, It gets resolved. What can be the reason? (only external monitor)

```
2024-03-28 23:18:20 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to ATC1.USBWakeup/HID Activity Using AC (Charge:80%) 5 secs
2024-03-28 23:18:25 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:80%) 10 secs
2024-03-28 23:18:35 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:80%) 3 secs
2024-03-28 23:18:38 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:80%) 16 secs
2024-03-28 23:18:54 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:80%) 3 secs
2024-03-28 23:18:57 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:80%)
2024-03-28 23:19:04 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:80%) 10 secs
2024-03-28 23:19:14 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to ATC1.USBWakeup/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:80%) 3 secs
2024-03-28 23:19:17 +0300 Sleep                 Entering DarkWake state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:80%) 1 secs
2024-03-28 23:19:18 +0300 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:80%)
```

Comment: plug in a keyboard mouse and power adapter

Comment: all of them plugged in. When I first try to wake it up, it immediately falls back asleep like above. it wakes up on my second or third attemps.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the two users pmset settings using terminal app

`pmset -g`

Pay attention to the lidwake value, it should be 1 not 0

Comment: Switching users resolves a defective hall effect sensor?